# IOError: Error reading file: failed to load HTTP resource, LXML error in Pythonanywhere

Tags: python, python-2.7, lxml, pythonanywhere

I am having a problem using lxml with python 2.7. I tried installing lxml version 3.4.0 and 3.4.2 but got the same error no idea why tho. Here is my python code:

```
@app.route("/getInformation", methods=['GET'])           
def domain(): 

    urlList = []

    urlList.append("http://gbgfotboll.se/serier/?scr=table&ftid=57109")
    urlList.append("http://gbgfotboll.se/serier/?scr=table&ftid=57108")

    date = '2015-04-18'

    # use this in real mode: currentDate = (time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))

    homeScore = "0"
    awayScore = "0"
    homeTeam = ""
    awayTeam = ""

    time_xpath = XPath("td[1]/span/span//text()[2]")
    team_xpath = XPath("td[2]/a/text()")
    league_xpath = XPath("//*[@id='content-primary']/h1//text()")

    for url in urlList:
        test =  0 #remove this
        rows_xpath = XPath("//*[@id='content-primary']/table/tbody/tr[td[1]/span/span//text()='%s']" % (date))
        html = lxml.html.parse(url)
    ....
```

And here is the errors i get:

```
2015-03-28 13:12:23,852 :Exception on /getInformation [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/Timocin/mysite/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/Timocin/mysite/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/Timocin/mysite/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/Timocin/mysite/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/Timocin/mysite/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/Timocin/mysite/work.py", line 48, in domain
    html = lxml.html.parse(url)
  File "/home/Timocin/mysite/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml/html/__init__.py", line 786, in parse
    return etree.parse(filename_or_url, parser, base_url=base_url, **kw)
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 3299, in lxml.etree.parse (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:72655)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1791, in lxml.etree._parseDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:106263)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1817, in lxml.etree._parseDocumentFromURL (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:106564)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1721, in lxml.etree._parseDocFromFile (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:105561)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1122, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDocFromFile (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:100456)
  File "parser.pxi", line 580, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:94543)
  File "parser.pxi", line 690, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:96003)
  File "parser.pxi", line 618, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:95015)
IOError: Error reading file 'http://gbgfotboll.se/serier/?scr=table&ftid=57109': failed to load HTTP resource
```

I was using the same code on another and it worked fine. But now i changed server i have no idea why im getting this error. Any ideas?

**EDIT1**

I tried using urllib2 instead and i got the following message:

```
2015-03-28 15:15:05,087 :Exception on /getInformation [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/Timocin/mysite/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/Timocin/mysite/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/Timocin/mysite/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/Timocin/mysite/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/Timocin/mysite/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/Timocin/mysite/work.py", line 57, in domain
    p = urlopen(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 448, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

**EDIT2**

I recently found out that you need to have a payed account to access external websites. I bought an account and it still dont work however the error messages changed, For lxml:

```
IOError: Error reading file 'https://gbgfotboll.se/serier/?scr=table&ftid=57109': failed to load external entity "https://gbgfotboll.se/serier/?scr=table&ftid=57109"
```

and for urllib2

```
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>
```

Comment: Could it be a network problem?

Comment: IOError: Error reading file 'http://gbgfotboll.se/serier/?scr=table&ftid=57109': failed to load HTTP resource --> Network connected?

Comment: Well as i said im running it on www.pythonanywhere.com so i doubt that their network is not connected?  @KlausD.

Comment: PythonAnywhere dev here -- we're talking about this in our forums too, so I'll add this link so that anyone else with the same problem can follow the discussion there: https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/2117/#id_post_13786